# How to change toolbar theme of libreoffice

Tags: office365, themes, ms-office, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

[image: Libreoffice toolbar theme]

I want the theme to be white color but here the theme is dark. how to change it to white.
I have check in Tools -> options but didn't find right option to fix it. Any idea on it highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the theme of your system? Most probably it is dark, and LO just uses that. -- Anyway, this issue of off-topic here, you might want ask at another site of the StackExchange network.